# THREE.ShaderMaterial opacity not working

Tags: javascript, three.js, shader, fragment-shader

I am switching to ShaderMaterial from MeshBasicMaterial in order to provide filters on my mesh textures. ShaderMaterial inherits from Material and hence opacity parameter is present. But changing this parameter doesn't change opacity of object. I am using THREE.HueSaturationShader which does not set alpha value.

I have added a very simple fiddle to showcase the situation
http://jsfiddle.net/thenectorgod/89aahytL/1/.

```
// BufferGeometry Tester

var hostDiv, scene, renderer, camera;

var WIDTH = 500;//window.innerWidth,
HEIGHT = 500;//window.innerHeight,
FOV = 35,
NEAR = 1,
FAR = 1000;

function init() {
hostDiv = document.createElement('div');
document.body.appendChild(hostDiv);

scene = new THREE.Scene();

renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });
renderer.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
renderer.setClearColor( 0x888888, 1 );
hostDiv.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(FOV, WIDTH / HEIGHT, NEAR, FAR);
camera.position.z = 50;
camera.lookAt(scene.position);
var geometry = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(20,20);
var material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
  transparent: true,
  depthTest: false
});
material.opacity = 0;
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
scene.add(mesh);
scene.add(camera);
animate();
}

function render() {
renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

function animate() {
requestAnimationFrame(animate);
render();
}

init();
```

Though I set the opacity to 0 the object is still visible.

How can I use both opacity and Shaders without adding extra opacity parameter in all of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your shader material has no shader. By default it renders something like `MeshBasicMaterial` but with a hardcoded GLSL color of red, and no transparency / opacity.

If you want a ShaderMaterial, you actually need to write GLSL shaders for it.

Comment: I am using THREE.HueSaturation shader as a shader for my program. There are many shaders which do not take opacity as a uniform parameter. In those cases how do we set opacity? Also there is no system to add multiple shader passes. So  will I have to modify all shaders to include opacity?

Comment: Yes. Whatever ends up being written in that shader's `gl_FragColor` is what ends up on screen (or texture). If `gl_FragColor.w == 1.0` there is no opacity, even if transparent is true. There is no system to add multiple shader passes unfortunately but you can look into `onBeforeRender`, i literally had that use case in mind when doing that pull request. Upon rendering an object, you would render it again using a different shader.